# TextBox addHandler for onFocus programmatically wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, textbox, delegates, event-handling

i am trying to add a `event handler` to the `textboxes` in a `grid`
so that i'v written the code below--->

```
// some code
foreach (var child in (o as Grid).Children)
 {
   if (child.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
   {
    child.AddHandler(OnGotFocus, new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox_GotFocus), true); //<---error                            
   }
 }
```

in above code i want to add an event handler for `onFocus` for all child `TextBoxes`.

but its getting some error here about `invalid arguments`, can any one fix this?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem--->

```
txtBox.GotFocus += (sender, eargs) =>
                                {
                                    if (txtBox.Text == StartingText[index])
                                        txtBox.Text = "";
                                };

txtBox.LostFocus += (sender, eargs) =>
                                {
                                    if (txtBox.Text == "")
                                        txtBox.Text = StartingText[index];
                                };
```